# How can i get a setMethod to input value one time, while being in a loop? is it impossible?

Tags: visual-c++, loops, getmethod

A loop that has a `setMethod` for a private variable.
I want this set-method to add value in the first turn of the loop, and then just stop.  How can i do that?

Code:

```
for(int x = 0; x > 5; x++)
{
   setnum(5);
   cout << getnum();
   setnum(getnum() -1);
}
```

this code should output: `1 2 3 4 5`

but when doing it it outputs: `5 5 5 5 5`
The `setnum(5)` is resetting.

**How to prevent it? with `setnum(5)` inside the loop.**

Comment: What is working of setnum() & getnum(), show code.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of > than put x < 5 and pass x as a parameter to setnum() method.

```
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
  setnum(x);

}
```